CORS problem using serverless framework v4. AWS
I’m facing a persistent CORS issue when trying to make a POST request from my frontend application to an API deployed with the Serverless Framework. My frontend is running on localhost:5173 (dev server) and the backend API endpoint is at https://zgrciu0uce.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/auth/createUserFromAdmin.
Error from the browser’s console
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://zgrciu0uce.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/auth/createUserFromAdmin' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
POST https://zgrciu0uce.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/auth/createUserFromAdmin net::ERR_FAILED

In serverless.yml, I added CORS configuration like this (I’ve just followed official docs):
functions:
  authCreateUserFromAdminHandler:
    handler: src/modules/Auth/handlers/createUserFromAdminHandler.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: auth/createUserFromAdmin
          method: post
          cors: true

In lambda function authCreateUserFromAdminHandler’s code:
export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context, callback: Function) => {
/* ... process information */
  const headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
    }
  const response = {
            statusCode: 201,
            headers,
            body: JSON.stringify({ OK: true })
        }
}

And in my frontend I run requests with Axios. Axios is configured this way:
import axios from 'axios'
import { useAuthStore } from '@/stores/authStore';
const authStore = useAuthStore();

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://zgrciu0uce.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
   'Authorization': `${authStore.tokenType} ${authStore.accessToken}`
  },
});
export { api }

Then in my .vue components, I just use the axios exported before:
import { api } from '@/libs/axios'

await api.post('/auth/createUserFromAdmin', newUser) // this line throws the error (see beginning of this post).

I wonder how could I fix this?
